# EA Scripting is not working

Tags: jscript, enterprise-architect

I have been using scripting in EA extensively for a couple of years.  This morning, I went into EA to start building a new script, and scripting no longer appears to work. I tried writing 'Hello World' and even wrote a script with syntax errors.  It does not detect the error nor does it run the script.

The only clue I've seen is when I tried manually driving scripts using the console.  When I open a console, it immediately closes (for all of the scripting languages).

Any ideas of how to get scripting back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I failed to mention (or recall) that I recently relocated EA into another folder to make room for a new installation but, unlike before, did not install the new version.  Therefore, EA was unable to find SScripter (or even a different version of SScripter).  As soon as I restored the original path, scripting started working again.

Comment: +1 as "**install EA**" is really useful answer also for future readers